# samba treat user as other or ignores group permissions

Tags: samba, permissions

I have a server running with Ubuntu 12.10 and several Clients running Windows 7. I use Samba as domain controller. Everything works fine except the shared folder. I made a shared folder and configured it like this:

```
[shared]
   comment = shared folder
   path = /srv/samba/shared
   browsable =yes
   guest ok = yes
   writeable = yes
   create mask = 2770
   directory mask = 2770
```

i also tried adding following options:

```
acl check permissions = no
valid users = @sambashare
force group = sambashare
```

the permissions for the shared folder are

```
2770
drwxrws--- 2 nobody sambashare
```

Several users are primary in the Group sambashare.

The problem is, i can't access the shared folder with any user in the sambashare group using Windows 7. The error message replies, that i don't have the permission.

If i change the rights of the shared folder to 777, like

```
sudo chmod 777 shared
```

everything works. But the shared folder should only be accessable for the users of the group sambashare.

Samba seem to ignore the permissions of a group or samba seem to treat the user as other, because if i change the permission of shared to 775, i can create new files in that folder but can't rename oder delete them even though the created file belongs to the user who created it. So i think samba treats the user as other, but why?

I googled a lot but found nothing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you manage to solve your problem?

Comment: having the same problem currently, debian9 samba 4.15